# Keeping the last duplicate index during a column pivot?

Tags: pandas, indexing, pivot

What is the Pandasic way of accomplishing the intent of the `keep='last'` parameter not currently supporterd by a `pivot` on, for example, the following `DataFrame`:

```
df.pivot(columns='a', keep='last')
```

Given this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'i':0 if random.random()<.5 else random.random(),'a':['abc','def','ghi','jkl'][int(random.random()*4)],'b':random.random(),'c':random.random()} for _ in range(20)])
df.i = df.i.cumsum()
df = df.set_index('i')

            a         b         c
i                                
0.000000  ghi  0.857628  0.856835
0.011049  abc  0.000408  0.189136
0.111914  ghi  0.785439  0.716488
0.111914  abc  0.168402  0.177056
0.111914  ghi  0.757416  0.763886
0.111914  ghi  0.807576  0.339000
0.574349  abc  0.508411  0.386711
0.574349  abc  0.347667  0.511798
0.650300  def  0.428700  0.176682
0.947907  def  0.308117  0.413609
1.503684  jkl  0.020903  0.974225
1.503684  jkl  0.836817  0.609914
1.659698  jkl  0.002263  0.508951
1.673570  jkl  0.552632  0.208657
1.673570  ghi  0.424978  0.573951
2.497983  jkl  0.657852  0.896766
2.994696  jkl  0.768899  0.988074
3.165982  def  0.848905  0.803382
3.480295  jkl  0.539529  0.772906
3.548527  abc  0.534413  0.974576
```

I'd like to keep only the last duplicate index entry while doing a:

```
df.pivot(columns='a')
```

Note that, for example, `i=0.111914` has values for both then all four of the intended `MultiIndex` columns for '`ghi`' and '`abc`' that must share a row with the common index `i=0.111914` .

Comment: what you expected

Comment: I changed the expectation to clarify what I wanted to do.